# Can someone shed some light on this ANR log?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-anr-dialog

Received this ANR report on the Developer Console, and I thought it was a bit weird. Seems like it's something with File, but I'm not too sure, so I was hoping someone could shed some light on it. Thanks a lot!

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=1)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a4b460 self=0xa0f828
  | sysTid=17417 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074566280
  | schedstat=( 10844308000 1221939000 8746 ) utm=972 stm=112 core=1
  at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:~197)
  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
  at java.io.File.getAbsoluteFile(File.java:387)
  at com.miz.mizuu.UpdateMovieService.onStart(UpdateMovieService.java:179)
  at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:438)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2359)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"DispatcherThread" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41966bf8 self=0xe63280
  | sysTid=17452 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=14719552
  | schedstat=( 280000 313000 4 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:118)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:118)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"AsyncTask #5" prio=5 tid=17 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x417c7f48 self=0xd01db0
  | sysTid=17440 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=13640192
  | schedstat=( 22850000 93316000 69 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x417c80b8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=17 (AsyncTask #5)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=16 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x417a2740 self=0xcff9b0
  | sysTid=17439 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=13604208
  | schedstat=( 39193000 106588000 94 ) utm=3 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x417a2878> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=16 (AsyncTask #4)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=15 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41774f28 self=0xcf3c48
  | sysTid=17438 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=13521264
  | schedstat=( 33842000 118576000 89 ) utm=3 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41775060> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=15 (AsyncTask #3)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=14 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41758038 self=0xc1aa70
  | sysTid=17437 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=12116520
  | schedstat=( 28508000 73514000 90 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41758170> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=14 (AsyncTask #2)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=13 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4174c610 self=0xcdb768
  | sysTid=17436 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=12394856
  | schedstat=( 31306000 75384000 71 ) utm=3 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4174c7c0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=13 (AsyncTask #1)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=12 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41651430 self=0xccafa0
  | sysTid=17434 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=11708720
  | schedstat=( 891000 182000 7 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x410c15b0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=12 (AsyncTask #2)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=10 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x410b2f88 self=0xc2c800
  | sysTid=17430 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=12473264
  | schedstat=( 453884000 188589000 1537 ) utm=35 stm=10 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x410ad570> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=10 (AsyncTask #1)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x410bddf0 self=0xbe3d70
  | sysTid=17428 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=12074328
  | schedstat=( 10983000 40959000 78 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x410bb088 self=0xb9f1a8
  | sysTid=17427 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=12303632
  | schedstat=( 14487000 37152000 88 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x410b6dd8 self=0xbd3300
  | sysTid=17426 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=12494048
  | schedstat=( 1417000 7766000 15 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1031)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1013)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:213)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x410b6c80 self=0xc44500
  | sysTid=17425 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=12500952
  | schedstat=( 19448000 5571000 36 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40a415d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang....
```

Comment: what are you doing in UpdateMovieService.java:179 onstart() . Post the code. Are you trying to concurrently modifying a file from threads?

Comment: It's simply checking if the file exists in that line. And no, it's only doing something to one file at a time. However, I do have a theory. Could this be caused by my service running in the background while the user tries to interact with the file in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the ANR was caused by the `Service` running for more than 5 seconds. Apparently a few users had a very large number of files that it had to go through. I've solved it by moving all the hard work to an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Just a note so no one gets confused reading this: It's not accessing a Service's functions for more than 5 seconds it's the onstart/oncreate/etc service lifecycle calls that happen on the main thread highlighted here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679315/how-to-avoid-anr-in-standalone-android-service