# Android configuration for JVoiceXML interpreter

Tags: android, vxml

I would like to ask a question about a code line mentioned in another question here: [How to avoid ANR in standalone android Service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10679315/2254541)

My question is about the line:

```
AndroidConfiguration config = new AndroidConfiguration();
```

Because I would like to make an Android application using the JVXML interpret, but so far I have no idea how to obtain this configuration, that I have to put as parameter in the following line:

```
jvxml = new JVoiceXmlMain(config);
```

I guess my question should be aimed on Mr. Marakatu, who asked the linked question, but I don't see any PM system on this web.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of JVoiceXML project manager, we made a functioning JVoiceXML Text Client for Android. The current version is available in android [repository branch](http://sourceforge.net/p/jvoicexml/code/4088/tree/branches/android/).

Where the package `org.jvoicexml.client.android` is the client itself, with configuration classes included in the source folder inside.

Comment: I tried to use mentioned configuration class. But in AndroidTextConfiguration class, it initiates an object of JVoiceXmlImplementationPlatformFactory, while this class has private instructor.